# System Uptime in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2009

How can I code to see how long the computer has been on.

Simple examples of code if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28VS.85%29.aspx) function see this example.

```
program Ticks;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

function TicksToStr(Ticks: Cardinal): string;    //Convert Ticks to String
var
  aDatetime : TDateTime;
begin
   aDatetime := Ticks  / SecsPerDay / MSecsPerSec;
   Result := Format('%d days, %s', [Trunc(aDatetime), FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss.z', Frac(aDatetime))]) ;
end;

begin
  try
     Writeln('Time Windows was started '+ TicksToStr(GetTickCount));
     Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**UPDATE**

to get the info in other format just must edit this line,

```
   Result := Format('%d days, %d hours %d minutes %d seconds ', [Trunc(aDatetime), HourOf(aDatetime),MinuteOf(aDatetime),SecondOf(aDatetime) ]) ;
```

and add the unit DateUtils.

Comment: Thats good for when, but I need how long like 4 days 3 hours 2 mins u see what i mean

Comment: Not that I know Delphi, but it looks like he has that there.

Comment: @RE Its a very good, detailed answer, and I don't need to run that through the compiler to see its perfect. He has answered your question in full, so I would suggest you accept it.

Comment: GetTickCount will wrap around to zero after ~49.7 days. Better use the performance counter 'System Up Time' or, on Vista and later versions, GetTickCount64.

Comment: As @OndrejKelle says, `GetTickCount` wraps around in 49.7 days so this should not be used to gather system uptime.

Answer (score 6):

Note that GetTickCount isn't really designed for accuracy.

For more reliable timing, use the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx)  and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28VS.85%29.aspx)  api calls:

```
function SysUpTime : TDateTime;
var
  Count, Freq : int64;
begin
  QueryPerformanceCounter(count);
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(Freq);
  if (count<> 0) and (Freq <> 0) then
  begin
    Count := Count div Freq;
    Result := Count / SecsPerDay;
  end
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Exactly how "accurate" do you require your uptime measurement to be?!?

Comment: Not much really - depend on what he wants to use it for. I seem to recall someone saying that GetTickCount may miss some millseconds, but I have no evidence of that - in retrospect, I suspect it was nonsense.

Comment: GetTickCount resolutions is usually [10ms or 16ms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I don't think that matters in range of days.